# GCP HTTP Load Balancer returns 502 error if POST data is large

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-http-load-balancer

We have an API server and are using HTTP Load Balancer. We found that the L7 Load balancer returns 502 error if HTTP request's data is large.

We have confirmed that it works when accessing the API without the Load Balancer (accessing the API Server directly.)

This question might be a similar issue. [HTTP Load Balancer cuts out part of a large request body](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27875626/http-load-balancer-cuts-out-part-of-a-large-request-body)

Someone said that using L4 Network Load Balancer is a possible solution but we don't want to use it for some reasons e.g. URL based load balancing and cross-region load balancing.

```
// Response OK (data size is 1024)
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"xx": "000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"}' https://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.com/xx/xxxxxxxxxxxx/xxxxxxxxx

// Response NG (data size is 1025)
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"xx": "00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"}' https://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.com/xx/xxxxxxxxxxxx/xxxxxxxxx
```

It seems that LB has some limitation about the size of post data. Tests show the limit is around 1024 bytes.

---

Update1

@chaintng [saved me](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30601075/curl-to-google-compute-load-balancer-gets-error-502). Someone on the linked post says that `curl` adds `"Expect: 100-continue Header"` if the post data is over 1024 byte.

```
// Response NG (data size is 1025. without "Expect: ")
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"xx": "00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"}' https://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.com/xx/xxxxxxxxxxxx/xxxxxxxxx

// Response OK (data size is 1025. with "Expect: ")
curl -H "Expect: " -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"xx": "00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"}' https://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.com/xx/xxxxxxxxxxxx/xxxxxxxxx
```

Comment: did you finally manage to get the solution yet ? i think i ran to the same issue :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

reference from this question [Curl to Google Compute load balancer gets error 502](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30601075/curl-to-google-compute-load-balancer-gets-error-502)

It's because CURL has default value when request large POST body defining header as `Expect: 100-continue`

Which is not support in Google L7 Load Balancing (stated in this document https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/load-balancing/http/)

All you have to do is ignoring this behaviour by set the header before execute curl.

For e.g. in PHP
`curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, ['Expect:']);`

Comment: Glad that it fixed.

Comment: for the `curl` command line, add this:  `--header "Expect:" `